# Set Form Value to Substring of Autocomplete Lookup Result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a jQueryUI autocomplete script that pulls results from a SQL query. It's all working great and the form field returns what I expect "Employee ID - Employee Name"

**autocomplete.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#emp_lookup").addClass("grey_text");
    $("#emp_lookup").autocomplete({
        source: "/lookup.php",
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

**lookup.php**

```
<?php
    // Query to get users
        $_emp_lookup = $_GET['term'];

        $q = "SELECT `emp_id`, `fn`, `ln`, `full_name`, `display_name`, `is_active` FROM `emp_info` WHERE (`emp_id` LIKE '%".$emp_lookup."%' OR `fn` LIKE '%".$emp_lookup."%' OR `ln` LIKE '%".$emp_lookup."%' OR `full_name` LIKE '%".$emp_lookup."%' OR `display_name` LIKE '%".$emp_lookup."%') AND `is_active` = 1";
        $r = mysqli_query($connect, $q);            

        $employee = array();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
                $result = $row['emp_id']." - ".$row['display_name'];
                array_push($employee, $result);
            }
        }else{
            $result = "No employee found";
            array_push($employee, $result);
        }

        $json = json_encode($employee);
        echo $json;
?>
```

The issue I'm running into is that when the form is submitted, I **only** want to pass the Employee ID to the processing script. So the fact that the Employee Name is in the autocomplete results is strictly for readability. The same way a DNS name makes it so we don't have to remember an IP address.

Comment: When the autocomplete is "selected" (or clicked), set the value of a hidden input to the employee ID.

Comment: But then would this submit the value of the form field as well as the hidden value?

Comment: Yes, but you only have to get form fields you care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a customer render method in jQuery UI autocomplete to parse the result your php script provides:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

For the PHP code, make sure you validate/sanitize the user input. Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: It is sanitized, I shortened the code for brevity. I'll look into the custom render. Thanks.